# Google analytics, adwords and a webshop

Tags: php, google-ads-api, webshop

I want to use the Google analytics API for managing some information.
Let's say I want to know who bought something in my webshop via adwords or not. So I can express my profit against my adwords visitors. 
I can't find a good place to start. Maybe someone knows where I can find the proper information?

I want to interact with Google Analytics via PHP.

Comment: Do you use a downloaded webshop like Magento? If so (maybe you thought of this already), maybe you could use its documentation or forums for help on this.

Comment: in the settings of the site on google analytics there is an option where you can set the site to an "e-commerce website". Then you will have to link every transaction to google analytics. Here you can find some more info and link to the google documentation : http://blog.kissmetrics.com/8-google-analytics-features/

Answer (score 0):

I managed this by using strings attached to the address (POST or GET method, I can't remember as I was just editing a pre-written cart), so I know when someone adds a product to the cart simply because in my analytics it shows up a page like

> ../cart.php?action=add&id=39

Comment: Thanks for commenting, but this is not what I seek. I'm looking for a E-Commerce implementation for product bought. So I can link it with Google Adwords and Analystics.